# Getting service info in the service fabric console application

Tags: azure-service-fabric

In the console application where the services are registered (ServiceRuntime.RegisterServiceAsync…) I want to know which services are configured (servicemanifest.xml).

Is there a way to access something like CodePackageActivationContext. 
In a service this is available using Context from the service base class, but in the console application there is no Context.

Is there a other way to get this info in the console application?
We need this info to know which services to register.
In our very dynamic environment the servicemanifest/applicationmanifest are generated and not all services are always needed.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to get the CodePackageActivationContext and the ServiceType descriptions:

```
var activationContext = FabricRuntime.GetActivationContext();
var serviceTypes = activationContext.GetServiceTypes();
```

And you'll probably need to create some kind of mapping between ServiceType and the `serviceFactory` delegate to use when registering it.